# How much heat do we lose perspirating?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, biophysics, estimation, biology

How can I calculate the heat my body loses from perspirating? For example, X Jouls per liter of sweat.

Comment: That would depend on quite a few factors, the concentration of water etc in the sweat etc but really it just comes down to the Latent heat of vapourisation of water.

Comment: @daniel: [perspirating is valid as well](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/perspirate), though I would admit that the perspiring is more common.